# mongoose findByIdAndUpdate instead of save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update the value of an element inside an array of my document.

The common way of update via `save` works as expected, but trying to use an `static` method, like `findByIdAndUpdate` doesn't work as expected.

Here bellow I paste the code I'm currently using:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nickname: { type: String, trim: true},
  username: { type: String, trim: true },
  notifications: [{
    a: {
      _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'x' },
      x: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'y' }
    },
    b: {
      _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'y' },
      x: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'y' }
    },
    read: { type: Number, default: 0 }, // 0 - Unread, 1 - read
    ts: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }]
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });

// This works as expected
UserSchema.statics.rNSave = function (user_id, notification_id) {
  var vm = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    vm.findById(user_id, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(new Error(err));
      } else {
        var notifications = data.notifications, i = 0;
        for (i; i < notifications.length; i += 1) {
          if (data.notifications[i]._id.toString() === notification_id) {
            data.notifications[i].read = 1;
            data.save({ validateBeforeSave: false }, function (err, updatedData) {
              if (err) {
                reject(new Error(err));
              } else {
                resolve();
              }
            });
            return;
          }
        }
        return reject('Error');
      }
    });
  });
};

// This one is not working
UserSchema.statics.rNStatic = function (user_id, notification_id) {
  return this.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: user_id, notifications: { $elemMatch: { _id: notification_id }}}, { $set: { 'notifications.$.read': 1 }}).exec();
};
```

Any help with this?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: are you getting any error. what output do you see.

Comment: This is my actual output: `"MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: notifications.$.read"`

Comment: also how does your document look. can you show that too. we can fix it by looking at your document structure. its just the issue with positional operator. you might be placing it wrong.

Comment: Isn't the model schema the structure of my data? I've placed at the beginning of my post

Comment: aha you cannot use $ in this case because you are labeling documents inside notification array with  a and b. positional operator is used when you have same kind of elements inside an array then you can use it. You might have to use it as notifications..read directly.

Comment: Understanding now how `$` works, The real case is I have to update the notification if it was read, how could I achieve that? Is this the correct way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130155/discussion-between-devstarlight-and-satish-chennupati).